How to set the same width of the multiple plots in R ggplot2?
I'm trying to draw the three bar plots in one image.
For the example data, I have a question about setting the width of each plot.
df <- data.frame(group=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
                 valueA=c(0.1, 0.06, 0.02, 0.09, 0.12),
                 valueB=c(0.4, 0.6, 0.55, 0.45, 0.52),
                 valueC=c(0.76, 0.79, 0.85, 0.94, 0.89))

A_bar <- ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=valueA, fill=group))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Group", y = "ValueA", fill = "Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.2),oob = rescale_none)+
  coord_flip()

A_bar <- A_bar + theme(legend.position="none", 
                       axis.text=element_text(size=12), 
                       axis.title=element_text(size=14))


B_bar <- ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=valueB, fill=group))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Group", y = "ValueB", fill = "Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.4,0.65),oob = rescale_none)+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  coord_flip()

B_bar <- B_bar + theme(legend.position="none", 
                           axis.text=element_text(size=12), 
                           axis.title=element_text(size=14),
                           axis.text.y=element_blank())


C_bar <- ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=valueC, fill=group))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Group", y = "ValueC", fill = "Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.7,1),oob = rescale_none)+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  coord_flip()

C_bar <- C_bar + theme(legend.position="none", 
                         axis.text=element_text(size=12), 
                         axis.title=element_text(size=14),
                         axis.text.y=element_blank())

ggarrange(A_bar, B_bar, C_bar, ncol=3, nrow=1)

Let the result figure follows as below:

You can see that the width of the first and the other plots are slightly different because of the y-axis title and labels in the first plot.
I want to unify the width of them like this.

I also tried to use facet_grid or facet_wrap, but it was confused because of the variables.
For the minor question, how can I insert the margin between the y-axis and bar plot as same as the ValueA plot?
Also, how can I change the order of the barplots from E~A to A~E?

You could create a fourth panel containing just the y-axis group labels:
old_bw <- theme_set(theme_bw())

theme_update(legend.position="none",                                   
             axis.title.y=element_blank(),
             axis.title.x=element_text(size=14),
             axis.text.y=element_blank(),
             axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
             plot.margin = unit(c(0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1), "cm"))

Y_axis <- ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=valueA, fill=group)) +
  labs(x = "Group", y="") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=14, color=0),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.2,0,0.2,0.2), "cm")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0), oob = scales::rescale_none)+
  coord_flip(); Y_axis
  
A_bar <- ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=valueA, fill=group))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  labs(x = "", y = "ValueA", fill = "Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.2), oob = scales::rescale_none)+
  coord_flip()

B_bar <- ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=valueB, fill=group))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  labs(x = "", y = "ValueB", fill = "Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.4,0.65), oob = scales::rescale_none)+
  coord_flip()

C_bar <- ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=valueC, fill=group))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  labs(x = "", y = "ValueC", fill = "Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.7,1),oob = scales::rescale_none)+
  coord_flip() 

Then use ggarrange to force equal widths on the 3 plots.
ggpubr::ggarrange(Y_axis, A_bar, B_bar, C_bar, ncol=4, nrow=1, 
        widths=c(1,6,6,6))

theme_set(old_bw)



Thank you for your kind reply! I'll try it and tell you if there are any problems. :)

No problem. For reversing the y-axis (x-axis before flipping), you can add scale_x_discrete(limits=rev) to each plot, including, importantly, the Y-axis plot.

One easy option to achieve your desired result with less code would be to use facetting which however requires to reshape your data. Additionally to apply the limits individually per panel I use ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales:
library(scales)
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggh4x'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     guide_axis_logticks

library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  valueA = c(0.1, 0.06, 0.02, 0.09, 0.12),
  valueB = c(0.4, 0.6, 0.55, 0.45, 0.52),
  valueC = c(0.76, 0.79, 0.85, 0.94, 0.89)
)

df |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-group) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = group, fill = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(
      name == "valueA" ~ scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.2), oob = rescale_none),
      name == "valueB" ~ scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.4, 0.65), oob = rescale_none),
      name == "valueC" ~ scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.7, 1), oob = rescale_none)
    )
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y = "Group", x = NULL, fill = "Group") +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background.x = element_blank()
  )


But when you want to stick with separate plots then I would suggest to switch to patchwork which since version 1.2.0 also allows to collect the axes, i.e. it is not necessary to remove the titles or text from the rightmost plots:

A_bar <- ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = valueA, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Group", y = "ValueA", fill = "Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.2), oob = rescale_none) +
  coord_flip()

A_bar <- A_bar + theme(
  legend.position = "none",
  axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
  axis.title = element_text(size = 14)
)


B_bar <- ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = valueB, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Group", y = "ValueB", fill = "Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.4, 0.65), oob = rescale_none) +
  coord_flip()

B_bar <- B_bar + theme(
  legend.position = "none",
  axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
  axis.title = element_text(size = 14)
)


C_bar <- ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = valueC, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Group", y = "ValueC", fill = "Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.7, 1), oob = rescale_none) +
  coord_flip()

C_bar <- C_bar + theme(
  legend.position = "none",
  axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
  axis.title = element_text(size = 14)
)

library(patchwork)

list(A_bar, B_bar, C_bar) |>
  wrap_plots(ncol = 3, nrow = 1) +
  plot_layout(axes = "collect")



Thank you for your detailed answer! Unfortunately, I couldn't install and call the ggh4x library. So I tried your second solution, but it returned error Error in is_valid_plot(..1) : the ... list contains fewer than 1 element...

I solved my problem by changing |> to %>% and plot_layout(axes = "collect") to plot_layout(guides = "collect"). Then it works well. Thank you so much!
